# Merging 2 int type strings into one UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, int, unix-timestamp

I have a table with 2 rows, one of which represents date and the other time.  These rows are not date format; they are int type and I can't change the original rows' type.  The date entries are written as 20120306, and the time entries are written, for example, 13000 for 01:30 UTC in 5 digits, and 130000 for 13:00 UTC in 6.  What I need to do is put both strings (date and time) into 1 UNIX timestamp.  I can either use this in a php script or merge them into a new table, whichever works best.  The problem for me is the php mysql syntax, functions and sequence for putting these 2 odd strings together into one timestamp.

If I can figure out how to do this, it would help me solve a whole mess of inaccuracies in a calendar reminder script I am trying to put together.  I have tried configuring these strings into times separately in the queries, but no matter how it's filtered, the outcome is right in some circumstances and wrong in others due to the nature of the original program.  If I had a PHD in PHP I would rewrite the entire program but I don't.  I am a major newbie at this.  So I just need to write my little PHP scripts to utilise what has already been provided.  Any help in my learning quest would be appreciated.

Comment: you can parse your date string '20120306'->'2012-03-06 ' but regarding time I don't understand '130000 for 13:30 UTC'. please explain more.

Comment: As you can find out in the [faq] and [ask], the way SO works is that you make an effort and post your code along with a specific question.  SO people generally do not just hand you complete solutions; you have to make an effort.

Comment: I have posted quite a bit of code concerning this issue and have had very excellent answers to parts of this problem.  I run the risk of having someone call my misbehaviour for reposting the same information several times.  So, do I repost the same stuff or do I try to ask a simple question with enough information for a logical answer so I can figure it out myself instead of asking for someone to write my whole script?  There are so many ambiguous rules on this site that you can't do one thing without being stung by another.  I shall excuse myself.  This system is too convoluted for reason.

Comment: I would also like to know how you conert '130000' to '13:30 UTC'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can also read [compound formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).
If you take a look at that list you will notice that your format is a close match to the "XMLRPC (Compact)" listed there.

It's your date string concatenated with a "t" and the time string. So, after you expanded your time string to length 6 (you already know how to do that), you can produce such a string and `strtotime()` will output your Unix time stamp:

```
$dt = "20120306";
$tm = "130000";
    
$unixTime = strtotime($dt . "t" . $tm);
```